# Linear algebra with a transformation i think

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, eigenfunctions

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space and let $P:V→V$ be a linear map such that $P^2 = P$. Which of the following must be true?

1. $P$ is invertible
2. $P$ is diagonalizable
3. $P$ is either the identity map or the zero map.

What can be said about the possible eigenvalues of $P$?

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Do you know any result about annihilating polynomials and diagonalization? If not, try to look that up first.

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is of the Jordan Canonical Form, then it is easy to verify that $P^2=P$ implies (2). In addition, you can verify that $P^2=P$ if and only if $P$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues in $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Ohk. So does it mean only option 2 is true? Because i P can be the zero transformation meaning P cannot be invertible

Comment: Yes. In fact, $P$ is invertible if and only if $P$ is the identiry map.

Comment: Ok thanks so much